# Browser address links doesn't works after expo:build web

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have make a webapp with react native and expo, with support of react navigation.

In my App.js I have:

```
const linking = {
    prefixes: ['https://example.com'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        Home: '', 
        Register: 'Register',
        Login: 'Login',
      }
    },
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
...
```

When I execute the expo as **expo start -https --web** I can navigate from browser links (for example https://example.com/Register or https://example.com/Login).
When I execute **expo build:web** and next **npx serve web-build -n -l 9000**, with a nginx reverse proxy at port 9000, and I if try to navigate from browser links I have a 404 error.

It is normal?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was npx serve...

I have reconfigured nginx to **root** directly the web-build generated by expo and now it's works